# DOES vs ISA in UNIVERSAL

Tags: perl, oop

I've never seen `DOES` in a Perl program before, and yet there it is in the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) on universal.

I don't understand completely what the difference between `DOES` and `ISA` is, though. The specification speaks of roles, perhaps accomplished through aggregation, delegation and mocking. The only kind of class relationship that I know about in Perl is inheritance through the @ISA array (or by using `parent` or `base`), and I think of roles as only being available with Moose and the like. The documentation also says that most of the time `DOES` and `ISA` will be the same thing.

Can you give an example where `DOES` and `ISA` return the different values? What is the practical difference between these two methods?

Comment: You've chosen an answer which is Moose specific. But the question is not Moose specific.

Comment: I think that's actually the point. Perl doesn't have any built-in distinction between the two, and leaves it up to library authors to implement how they please. In a vanilla Perl program there is no difference. You only find it when you use one of these OOP libs like Moose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use roles. `UNIVERSAL::DOES` behaves the same as `UNIVERSAL::isa`, but Moose, Mouse, and Moo all provide `DOES` methods on their object classes that return true for classes that consume a given role.

Comment: So it's there solely to be overridden by frameworks that provide roles, rather than supporting any sort of native idea of a role?

Comment: No, you're free to override `DOES` manually too. (You can of course override `isa` but most cases of doing so are to make it return untruths.)

Comment: An [example](https://metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/Type-Tiny-0.032/lib/Type/Tiny.pm#L958) of overriding it manually, so that Type::Tiny type constraints return true for `$type->DOES("Type::API::Constraint")`. [Type::API::Constraint](https://metacpan.org/pod/Type::API::Constraint) is entirely documentation/specification - it is not a role in the Moose sense.

Comment: @NateGlenn more or less yes. tobyink is right in that it doesn't have to be only "for frameworks", but you're right that there's no built-into-perl concept that makes `DOES` do anything interesting; it has to be provided by code.

Comment: @tobyink Thanks for the examples. Why does the example use `!!1`? Doesn't that just equal `1`? And when would `"UNIVERSAL"->can("DOES")` return false?

Comment: @NateGlenn `UNIVERSAL->can("DOES")` returns false on old versions of perl (old versions of UNIVERSAL) before DOES was added. I think that was in 5.12.0.

Comment: @NateGlenn - `!!1` and `1` are different - this can be verified using Devel::Peek. However, they act the same if you treat them as a string, a number, or a boolean (i.e. virtually always). @hobbs: UNIVERSAL::DOES was added in Perl 5.10, but Type::Tiny supports 5.6.1 and above.